# "no operator "!=" matches these operands" for Iterator comparison after migration to VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am upgrading a VC++6 project into VS2015. I have an `if` statement which is checking an iterator against being `NULL` (actually 0). The code is building in VC++6 and VS2003 without any error but in VS2015 it throws error. here is the code:

Here are the type definitions:

```
#define NULL    0    

typedef std::list <bscTrk *> bscTL;
typedef bscTL::iterator bscTLI;     // data type of iterator into trunk linked list

typedef struct 
 {
  int   TSNum;                  
  bscTLI    tli;        // iterator of a trunk to be reset
 } TnkReset;
extern TnkReset gTnkReset;
```

Here is the piece code throwing error in VS2015:

```
if (gTnkReset.tli != NULL)   
     ResetRadTnk (gTnkReset.tli);
```

Error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State   Detail Description
>   Error (active)      no operator "!=" matches these operands BSCC
>   operand types are: bscTLI != int

I have tried Nullptr but it didn't help.What is the problem here?

Comment: What is `bscTL` ? generally you should check with *end* iterator, some default construct iterator may serve as sentinel, you may so try `gTnkReset.tli != {}`

Comment: it's a list: typedef std::list <bscTrk *> bscTL;

Answer (score 1):

You should never compare iterators to anything else than other iterators from the same container. The proper way to initialize an "empty" iterator is to give it the value of `end()` from its container.

```
std::list<int> list;
auto itor = list.end();

// ...

if (itor == list.end())
   // itor is not pointing anywhere interesting
```

As for why you're having this error now with 2015, but not with 2003 or (gasp!) 6.0, the implementation of iterators in Visual C++'s standard library has changed over time. It might have had a constructor taking a pointer or some weird `operator==`, who knows.

Comment: ggggg... from our table to your table

Answer (score 1):

I would venture there is a bug in original code.

You're looking for non-NULL data in the list, so you should go from iterator to the list data, need comparison so iterator should be dereferenced

```
if (*(gTnkReset.tli) != NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks Severin, your are right, it seems the code has bug and it has to check the list not the iterator.